# Firebase go sdk: dynamic link generation (email link for signin vs generic dynamic link)

Tags: firebase, go, firebase-admin

I am trying to use dynamic link feature (user to user share) as [here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/dynamic-links/use-cases/user-to-user) using go. The official sdk has one API similar to what I want. See [here](https://godoc.org/firebase.google.com/go/auth#Client.EmailSignInLink). But, Is that API only for SignIn or can it be used to make any dynamic link using firebase. Does firebase make any distinction about dynamic link whether it is for signin or other action. I see also a specific section for [email link for signin](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/admin/email-action-links#generate_email_link_for_sign-in) in the doc and this API may be exclusively for that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no implicit connection between links generated by Firebase Dynamic Links, and links generated by Firebase Authentication.

You could possibly pass a sign-in link along with the dynamic link, but I must admit I've never done that.

If you're trying to auto-redirect users to the application after they click the sign-in link, you can pass a redirect link in when you [generate the sign-in URL with Firebase Authentication](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/android/email-link-auth#enable_email_link_sign-in_for_your_firebase_project). However this API is not available in the Admin SDKs (such as the one for Go), but only in client-side SDKs.

Comment: thank you so much for your help. Looking further, I too see the distinction and see auto generated API here https://godoc.org/google.golang.org/api/firebasedynamiclinks/v1 Looking at the source, the admin EmailSigninLink is sent to Identity Toolkit REST API . Not sure the autogenerated API libraries are stable and user friendly. But will try. Thanks again

Comment: Frank. As you are with Firebase, what do you think of the auto generated api for go. Are they widely used or intend to. I am just exploring firebase so get bit overwhelmed with all the options.

Comment: I have no specific opinion there. If you stay within the documented API, it should remain the same within the same major version.